# Working Animation Frame Code?

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, sdk, frame

I've been working on frame animation for a week now, and every code I've used has a tremendous amount of errors and doesn't work. Is there a code that has worked for you?

Comment: define "frame animation".  You want to alter the origin and size of a view object over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you getting out of memory errors? Try calling setCallback(null) on your animation images when you are finished with them.  Also take a look at the code for Replica Island plenty of animations there :)